Problem with Assembly Program: 'Enter Filename' Prompt is Overlapping with 'Enter String' Prompt Without Waiting for User Input
Here is my program code:
%define BUFFER_READ_WRITE 3000

section .bss
    buffer_str resb BUFFER_READ_WRITE          ; reserve buffer for string input
    buffer_filename resb BUFFER_READ_WRITE     ; reserve buffer for filename input
    function_choice resb 1                     ; contains one digit for function selection

section .data
    str_prompt db 'Enter string: ', 0          ; prompt for entering a string
    str_prompt_len equ $-str_prompt            ; length of the prompt

    filename_prompt db 'Enter filename: ', 0   ; prompt for entering a filename
    filename_prompt_len equ $-filename_prompt  ; length of the filename prompt

    function_menu db '1. Enter and edit file', 10, '2. Exit', 10, 0   ; function menu
    function_menu_len equ $-function_menu      ; length of the function menu

    error_open_msg db 'Failed to open file', 10, 0     ; error message for file open failure
    error_open_len equ $-error_open_msg        ; length of the open file error message

    error_write_msg db 'Failed to write to file', 10, 0   ; error message for file write failure
    error_write_len equ $-error_write_msg      ; length of the write file error message

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    loop:
        ; Print function menu
        mov rsi, function_menu
        mov rdx, function_menu_len
        call print

        ; Get function selection from user
        mov rsi, function_choice
        mov rdx, 1
        call get_input

        ; Compare and branch based on function selection
        cmp byte [function_choice], '1'
        je write_file_function

        cmp byte [function_choice], '2'
        je exit_program
        jmp loop

; Function implementations
exit_program:
    ; Exit program
    mov rax, 60
    xor rdi, rdi
    syscall

print:
    ; Print string
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    syscall
    ret

get_input:
    ; Get string input
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
    ret

write_file_function:
    ; Get filename from user
    mov rsi, filename_prompt
    mov rdx, filename_prompt_len
    call print
    mov rsi, buffer_filename
    mov rdx, BUFFER_READ_WRITE
    call get_input

    ; Get string to write to file
    mov rsi, str_prompt
    mov rdx, str_prompt_len
    call print
    mov rsi, buffer_str
    mov rdx, BUFFER_READ_WRITE
    call get_input

    ; Write string to file
    mov rsi, buffer_str
    mov rdx, BUFFER_READ_WRITE
    mov rdi, buffer_filename
    call write_file
    jmp loop

write_file:
    ; Open -> write -> close file
    ; Open file with write permission
    mov rax, 2                ; syscall number for sys_open
    mov rsi, 577              ; flags (O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC)
    mov rdx, 0644             ; mode (rwxr--r--)
    syscall
    test rax, rax
    js error_open
    mov r8, rax               ; file descriptor

    ; Write to file
    mov rax, 1                ; syscall number for sys_write
    mov rdi, r8               ; file descriptor
    syscall
    test rax, rax
    js error_write

    ; Close file
    mov rax, 3                ; syscall number for sys_close
    mov rdi, r8               ; file descriptor
    syscall
    ret

error_open:
    ; Print file open error message
    mov rsi, error_open_msg
    mov rdx, error_open_len
    call print
    jmp exit_program

error_write:
    ; Print file write error message
    mov rsi, error_write_msg
    mov rdx, error_write_len
    call print
    jmp exit_program

The program above prints a menu and asks the user to press 1 to enter a filename and the content to write to it, or press 2 or any other key to exit. But there is an issue with the write_file_function (Image enter image description here) and the output (quick read, no need to see the image):
Note: The autoasm.sh script is just a file for compiling, linking, and running the binary. It does not affect the output.
oen@oen-Latitude-E7440:~/oEn_file/asm/x64-roadmap/do_tasks/file$ autoasm.sh chuong_trinh.asm 
1. Enter and edit file
2. Exit
1
Enter filename: Enter string: 

Description: If, as required, when the user presses 1, the program should print "Enter filename:" and wait for the user to input, and then proceed to "Enter string:", but somehow it prints both prompts immediately. I don't know how to handle this. It seems similar to an instruction drift error in Java, but I'm not sure if that's the case. I hope you can help or provide some suggestions. Thank you for reading.
I have tried:

Adding a loop to separate the code segments for entering the filename and the content into the file, but it didn't
I have modified it as follows, but it didn't work:

write_file_function:
    .loop:
        ; Get filename from user
        mov rsi, filename_prompt
        mov rdx, filename_prompt_len
        call print
        mov rsi, buffer_filename
        mov rdx, BUFFER_READ_WRITE
        call get_input

        mov al, byte [buffer_filename]
        cmp al, 0
        je .loop
        jne .write_to_file

    .write_to_file:
        ; Get string to write to file
        mov rsi, str_prompt
        mov rdx, str_prompt_len
        call print
        mov rsi, buffer_str
        mov rdx, BUFFER_READ_WRITE
        call get_input

    ; Write string to file
    mov rsi, buffer_str
    mov rdx, BUFFER_READ_WRITE
    mov rdi, buffer_filename
    call write_file
    jmp loop


What do you mean by "instruction drift"?  I think this phrase might be the result of a Google mistranslation.  Please try to explain it in other words ... or provide a link to a document that explains the concept that you are talking about.  And what Java Input Stream issues are you referring to?

Yes, I used Google to translate it because I didn't know the name of the error I encountered; I only noticed it seemed similar to an issue in Java.

"Consecutive string printing error"  doesn't make much sense either.  Please explain in detail what you are talking about.   We can't help you if we can't understand what you are asking.

Yes, after your explanation, the error is due to the newline. So I need to remove it from the string, but is it in the buffer_filename string or another variable?

I changed function_choice to 2, but it didn’t change the output

Additionally, I added code to remove the newline character in function_choice immediately after the user inputs their choice, but I encountered a segmentation fault ^^

Unrelated to your question, but 0644 isn't an octal constant in NASM.  You want 0q644 or 0o644.

@MichaelPetch: When you make a read system call with RDX = 1, Linux will only read 1 character into the memory of your process.  If the user typed a digit and pressed enter, then there will still be an unread newline in the kernel's input buffer.  It won't be in this code's buffer_str buffer until the next read system call from that fd.  I think the OP might have been confused by your explanation :/

Thank you for the suggestions, I was able to fix it.
